# What is the difference between sscanf or atoi to convert a string to an integer?

Tags: c, scanf, atoi

gcc 4.4.4 c89

What is better to convert a string to an integer value.

I have tried 2 different methods atoi and sscanf. Both work as expected.

```
char digits[3] = "34";
int device_num = 0;

if(sscanf(digits, "%d", &device_num) == EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: Incorrect value for device\n");
    return FALSE;
}
```

or using atoi

```
device_num = atoi(digits);
```

I was thinking that the sscanf would be better as you can check for errors. However, atoi doesn't doing any checking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to integer C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

1. `atoi`

This is probably the fastest if you're using it in performance-critical code, but it does no error reporting. If the string does not begin with an integer, it will return 0. If the string contains junk after the integer, it will convert the initial part and ignore the rest. If the number is too big to fit in `int`, the behaviour is unspecified.

2. `sscanf`

Some error reporting, and you have a lot of flexibility for what type to store (signed/unsigned versions of `char/short/int/long/long long/size_t/ptrdiff_t/intmax_t`).

The return value is the number of conversions that succeed, so scanning for `"%d"` will return 0 if the string does not begin with an integer. You can use `"%d%n"` to store the index of the first character after the integer that's read in another variable, and thereby check to see if the entire string was converted or if there's junk afterwards. However, like `atoi`, behaviour on integer overflow is unspecified.

3. `strtol` and family

Robust error reporting, provided you set `errno` to 0 before making the call. Return values are specified on overflow and `errno` will be set. You can choose any number base from 2 to 36, or specify 0 as the base to auto-interpret leading `0x` and `0` as hex and octal, respectively. Choices of type to convert to are signed/unsigned versions of `long/long long/intmax_t`.

If you need a smaller type you can always store the result in a temporary `long` or `unsigned long` variable and check for overflow yourself.

Since these functions take a pointer to pointer argument, you also get a pointer to the first character following the converted integer, for free, so you can tell if the entire string was an integer or parse subsequent data in the string if needed.

---

Personally, I would recommend the `strtol` family for **most** purposes. If you're doing something quick-and-dirty, atoi might meet your needs.

As an aside, sometimes I find I need to parse numbers where leading whitespace, sign, etc. are not supposed to be accepted. In this case it's pretty damn easy to roll your own for loop, eg.,

```
for (x=0; (unsigned)*s-'0'<10; s++) 
    x=10*x+(*s-'0');
```

Or you can use (for robustness):

```
if (isdigit(*s))
    x=strtol(s, &s, 10);
else /* error */
```

Comment: The `errno` in `strtol` is implementation specific feature as stated in man page of strtol(3). To validate correctly, you should pass endptr. If **endptr is '\0' after `strtol`, then the string is parsed as a whole and is valid (or its length is zero).

Comment: @Zouppen: No idea where you got that info, but it's wrong. "The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno." (C99 7.20.1.4 paragraph 8)

Comment: However you are right that you need to check other conditions. Only overflow is an "error". Failure to make any conversion should be detected via `endptr`, and if you insist that the entire string be consumed, you should also check that.

Comment: You are correct about that. Only EINVAL behaviour is somewhat implementation specific.

Answer (score 10):

`*scanf()` family of functions return the number of values converted.  So you should check to make sure `sscanf()` returns 1 in your case.  `EOF` is returned for "input failure", which means that `ssacnf()` will never return `EOF`.

For `sscanf()`, the function has to parse the format string, and then decode an integer.  `atoi()` doesn't have that overhead.  Both suffer from the problem that out-of-range values result in undefined behavior.

You should use `strtol()` or `strtoul()` functions, which provide much better error-detection and checking.  They also let you know if the whole string was consumed.

If you want an `int`, you can always use `strtol()`, and then check the returned value to see if it lies between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Comment: as an additional bonus for `strtol` etc if you set your *base* to `0` you get automatic choice of the conversion from octal, decimal or hexadecimal input.

Comment: A potential concern to using base 0 is that strings beginning with `0` will be interpreted as base 8 (octal).  This behavior is expected with knowledgeable users, but too many folks are not _octal_ aware and are surprised to find  `012` becomes 10 and `019` becomes 1 as the conversion stopped due to the non-octal digit 9.

Answer (score 4):

To @R..  I think it's not enough to check `errno` for error detection in `strtol` call.

```
long strtol (const char *String, char **EndPointer, int Base)
```

You'll also need to check `EndPointer` for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Combining R.. and PickBoy answers for brevity

```
long strtol (const char *String, char **EndPointer, int Base)

// examples
strtol(s, NULL, 10);
strtol(s, &s, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

When there is no concern about invalid string input or range issues, use the simplest: `atoi()`

Otherwise, the method with best error/range detection is neither `atoi()`, nor `sscanf()`.
[This good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421555/2410359) all ready details the lack of error checking with `atoi()` and *some* error checking with `sscanf()`.

`strtol()` is the most stringent function in converting a string to `int`.  Yet it is only a start.  Below are detailed examples to show proper usage and so the reason for this answer after the [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421555/2410359).

```
// Over-simplified use
int strtoi(const char *nptr) {
  int i = (int) strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10);
  return i; 
}
```

This is the like `atoi()` and neglects to use the error detection features of `strtol()`.

To fully use `strtol()`, there are various features to consider:

1. Detection of *no conversion*: Examples: `"xyz"`, or `""` or `"--0"`?  In these cases, `endptr` will match `nptr`.

   ```
   char *endptr;
   int i = (int)strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);
   if (nptr == endptr) return FAIL_NO_CONVERT;
   ```
2. Should the whole string convert or just the leading portion: Is `"123xyz"` OK?

   ```
   char *endptr;
   int i = (int)strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);
   if (*endptr != '\0') return FAIL_EXTRA_JUNK;
   ```
3. Detect if value was so big, the the result is not representable as a `long` like `"999999999999999999999999999999"`.

   ```
   errno = 0;
   long L = strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);
   if (errno == ERANGE) return FAIL_OVERFLOW;
   ```
4. Detect if the value was outside the range of than `int`, but not `long`.  If `int` and `long` have the same range, this test is not needed.

   ```
   long L = strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);
   if (L < INT_MIN || L > INT_MAX) return FAIL_INT_OVERFLOW;
   ```
5. Some implementations go beyond the C standard and set `errno` for additional reasons such as [errno to EINVAL in case no conversion was performed](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or [`EINVAL`  The value of the Base parameter is not valid.](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf2/strtol.htm).  The best time to test for these `errno` values is implementation dependent.

Putting this all together:  (Adjust to your needs)

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int strtoi(const char *nptr, int *error_code) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long i = strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);

  #if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN || LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
  if (errno == ERANGE || i > INT_MAX || i < INT_MIN) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    i = i > 0 : INT_MAX : INT_MIN;
    *error_code = FAIL_INT_OVERFLOW;
  }
  #else
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    *error_code = FAIL_OVERFLOW;
  }
  #endif

  else if (endptr == nptr) {
    *error_code = FAIL_NO_CONVERT;
  } else if (*endptr != '\0') {
    *error_code = FAIL_EXTRA_JUNK;
  } else if (errno) {
    *error_code = FAIL_IMPLEMENTATION_REASON;
  }
  return (int) i;
}
```

---

Note: All functions mentioned allow leading spaces, an optional leading *sign* character and are affected by *locale* change.  Additional code is required for a more restrictive conversion.

---

Note: Non-OP title change skewed emphasis.  This answer applies better to original title "convert string to integer sscanf or atoi"

Answer (score 0):

If user enters 34abc and you pass them to atoi it will return 34.
If you want to validate the value entered then you have to use isdigit on the entered string iteratively