# Receiving an Integer command line argument

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that takes a single command line argument. This argument needs to be in the range [0, INT_MAX]. What is the best way to take argv[1] and convert it into an int, while ensuring that it will be a valid integer?

Comment: Do you have an `atoi()` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string to integer sscanf or atoi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420629/convert-string-to-integer-sscanf-or-atoi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`argv[1]` is the first commandline arg and [strtoul()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/) converts to an unsigned integer

Also argc is the number of arguments, so check it is at least 2 (argc counts the program name) before calling `argv[1]`

Strictly strtoul() is c++ but most c compilers support it in their standard library, it takes a 'c' style char * string

Comment: I think you meant, "arg 0 is the program name".

Comment: @the first arg as far as argc is concerned is the program name - will try and make it clear

Comment: `int number = 0; sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &number);`

Comment: `strtoul()` was in C89 before it was in C++.  If you're being really thorough, you'd have to check rather carefully for the error returns from any of the `strtoX()` families of functions, probably using a wrapper function.