# Unsigned char to char* and int in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, char, int, unsigned-char

Working on some encryption that requires unsigned char's in the functions, but want to convert to a char for use after it's been decrypted. So, I have:

```
unsigned char plaintext[16];
char *plainchar;
int plainint;

... Code now populates plaintext with data that happens to all be plain text
```

Now at this point, let's say plaintext is actually a data string of "0123456789". How can I get the value of plaintext into plainchar as "012456789", and at the same time plainint as 123456789?

-- Edit --

Doing this when plaintext is equal to "AAAAAAAAAA105450":

```
unsigned char plaintext[16];
char *plainchar;
int plainint;

... Code now populates plaintext with data that happens to all be plain text

plainchar = (char*)plaintext;
```

Makes plainchar equal to "AAAAAAAAAA105450╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠┤∙7" with a sizeof = 51. The encryption code is the rijndael example code, so it should be working fine.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I *hope* you're not thinking that the string "1234" (0x31323334) is in any way equivalent to the binary character array "0x01020304".  Just checking ;)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plain text string is not terminated. All strings must have an extra character that tells the end of the string. This character is `'\0'`.

Declare the `plaintext` variable as

```
unsigned char plaintext[17];
```

and after you are done with the decryption add this

```
plaintext[last_pos] = '\0';
```

Change `last_pos` to the last position of the decrypted text, default to `16` (last index of the array).

Comment: Wow. I've been out of C for too long. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think its simply

```
plainchar = (char*)plaintext;
sscanf( plainchar, "%d", &plainint );
```

Answer (score 1):

for unsigned char to char*

```
plainchar = (char*)plaintext;
```

for unsigned to int

```
sscanf( plainchar, "%d", &plainint );
```

Comment: check your encryption algorithm

Comment: @BenCurtis: Update your question rather than using comments.

Comment: Thanks (and to @Sodved), except this doesn't create expected results for me. For some reason, if plaintext is "AAAAAA123456" and I do the above, plainchar is now equal to "AAAA123456<random gibberish data>" and sizeof reports 51. Thoughts?

Comment: @BenCurtis Surely you meant `strlen` reports 51? `sizeof` only cares about the _type_ of its argument, `sizeof plainchar` is the size of a `char*`, regardless of what the contents of `plaintext` are.