# Argv parameters conversion

Tags: command-line, parameters, argv, argc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string to integer C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c)

I wanted to convert a number I received from the command argv[1] into an "int". I know the argv is stored as a string, but how can I get an integer value from them. Supposing argv[1] = 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `atoi()` function from the C standard library:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi

Comment: -1 for adivising the use of a non-standard function where a standard one is available AND answering using a link only.

Comment: @H2CO3 You're wrong, `atoi` is standardized - both C and C++ standards include it. Maybe you had `itoa` in mind?

Comment: @jons34yp absolutely right! I'm always confusing these. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX C library includes different functions to convert strings to actual numerical values. Here are a few examples:

```
long some_long = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
long long some_longlong = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);
unsigned long some_unsigned_long = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
unsigned long long some_unsigned_longlong = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);
```

There are functions even for conversion to floating-point values:

```
double some_double = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
float some_float = strtof(argv[1], NULL);
long double some_long_double = strtold(argv[1], NULL);
```

For further reference, [read here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) and some more places (strtoul.html and strtod.html on the same web page).