# Restrict user input to 8 digit number

Tags: c, validation, int

I am looking to have a user enter an 8 digit account number. The code I have seems to work for everything unless you have multiple letters, i.e.: 'bbb' as an input. If that happens, it runs the while loop 3 times, displaying the printf, but not asking for another input.

Any input on how to fix this, or a better way to do it is welcome!

Right now, I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int return_val = 0;
int account_number = 0;
int within_range = 0;

printf("Please enter your 8 digit account number:\n");
return_val = scanf("%d", &account_number);
getchar();
getchar();

if((account_number > 9999999) && (account_number < 99999999))
{
    within_range = 1;
}

while ((return_val != 1) || (within_range != 1))  
{
    printf("Invalid account number. Account number must be 8 digits.\n");
    printf("Please enter your 8 digit account number: \n");
    //scanf("%d", &clear);
    return_val = scanf("%d", &account_number);
    getchar();
    getchar();

    if((account_number > 9999999) && (account_number < 99999999))
    {
        within_range = 1;
    }
}

printf("Account #: %d", account_number);
}
```

Comment: You should probably read it as a string, then validate its length and numeric content, then finally convert to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it help if you read the input as a string of characters (using `fgets`) and parse it from there using `sscanf`?  You will not have to worry about the extra `getchar`s.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_acct_num()
{
    char line[80];
    int  acct_num;
    int return_val = 0;
    printf("Please enter your 8 digit account number:\n");
    fgets ( line, sizeof ( line ), stdin );
    return_val = sscanf(line, "%d", &acct_num);
    if ( return_val != 1 )
        return ( 0 );
    if ( ( acct_num < 10000000 ) || ( acct_num > 99999999 ) )
        return ( 0 );

    return ( acct_num );
}

int main()
{
    int account_number = 0;
    while ( ! ( account_number = get_acct_num() ) )
        printf("Invalid account number. Account number must be 8 digits.\n");


    printf("Account #: %d", account_number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is better to parse a string

```
#include <ctype.h>
...

char input[200];

scanf("%s", input);

int len = strlen(input);
int dig = 0;

if (len == 8) {
  for ( ; dig<len ; dig++) if ( ! isdigit(input[dig])) break;
}

if (dig == 8) printf("OK\n");
else printf("Not ok\n");
```

the code ensures we have 8 digits and nothing else in input (prints "OK").

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int account_number = 0;
    int inval = 0;
    char acc_buf[256];
    printf("Please enter your 8 digit account number:\n");
    scanf("%s", acc_buf);
    if (strlen(acc_buf) == 8) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            if (!isdigit(acc_buf[i])) {
                inval++;
                break;
            }
    } else inval++;
    if (!inval) {
        account_number = atoi(acc_buf);
        printf("Account #: %d\n", account_number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will work, but requires <string.h>.  I'm pretty sure the "%8d" will work just using <stdio.h>.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a little rewrite?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* this is for strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* this is for atoi */

int main()
{
    char input [55]; /* this is to store the user input */

    int account_number = 0;

    printf("Please enter your 8 digit account number:\n");

    while (fgets(input, 55, stdin)[0] == '\n')
        ;  /* this is a safer way to get input, loop until there is input, ignore new lines */

     account_number = atoi(input); /* convert to an int */

    if (account_number < 10000000 || account_number > 99999999) 
        return -1; 
    /* quit if invalid input */

    printf("Account #: %d\n", account_number);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I've used `fgets` here and `atoi` as I think it would be good to be familiar with those functions. Having said that `atoi` is not necessarily the best way to convert to an number. [Strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) is far more reliable but a little more complicated to use.

This is one way to use `strtol` in this context:

```
 char* temp = 0;
 account_number = strtol(input, &temp, 10); /* convert to an int */
```

More on the subject of converting strings to numbers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c).

EDIT-2:
Taking into account chux's comment, the loop can be constructed like this too:

```
char* out;
do
{
    out = fgets(input, 55, stdin);
}
while (out == NULL || out[0] == '\n')
    ;
```

Comment: Under rare circumstances, an EOF (via redirected input) or I/O error  causes `fgets()` to return NULL.  In these exceptional situations, `fgets(input, 55, stdin)[0]` will likely crash.

Comment: Noted, thanks, I've updated my post to suggest a simple way to handle NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like using `scanf()`, prefer `fgets()`, then `sscanf()`.
Details below.
2 key lines:

```
if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL)
...
while (1 != sscanf(buf, " %8lu %c", &AccontNummner, &ch));
```

Solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Get 8 digit account number.  Returns -1 on I/O error or EOF
// Parsing error just tries again.
long Get8DigitAccountNumber(void) {
  const char *prompt = "Enter 8 digit account number: ";
  unsigned long AccontNummner;
  char ch;  // Extra text
  char buf[1024];
  do { // or while (1)
    ch = '\0';
    printf(prompt);
    fflush(stdout);  // Appears to be needed on some systems.
    prompt = "Error, try again: ";  // Used on re-try
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) {
      return -1;  // handle I/O error
    }
  // If not _exactly_ one 1-8 digit field parsed, then try again.
  // Leading and trailing whitespaces are OK
  } while (1 != sscanf(buf, " %8lu %c", &AccontNummner, &ch));
  return (long) AccontNummner;
}

int main() {
  long AccontNummner;
  while ((AccontNummner = Get8DigitAccountNumber()) >= 0) {
    printf("# %lu\n", AccontNummner);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to read *exactly* 8 digits ...

```
  int n1 = 0;
  int n2 = 0;
  } while ((1 != sscanf(buf, " %n%8lu%n %c", &n1, &AccontNummner, &n2, &ch) || ((n2 - n1) != 8));
```

---

Acceptable format: [optional whitespaces][1-8 digits][optional whitespaces][nothing more]
`sscanf()` format: `" %8lu %c"`.
Use `%u` instead of `%d` to not allow `'-'`.
Explicitly allow optional leading and trailing spaces.
The `%c` catches any non-white char after the 8-digit number.
Scanning anything via `%c` causes `sscanf()` to return 2.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I fooled with formatted input in C but try scanf("%8d", &account_number);

Comment: This does not work.  It looks for at most 8 digit input but not exactly 8 digits as required.

Comment: I don't see where it is required to have an 8 digit mask, just 8 digits input.  Speculating here, but this looks like a homework assignment so I think using <string.h> is a mistake (though a good way to do this).  BUT, you could just add the leading zeros to get an 8-digit account number in the format specifiers of the printf statement.

Comment: I am sure it is a homework assignment but he has made an honest effort and is stuck.  I believe it is an 8 digit mask because of the way he has structured his original code, checking for 8 digit input.

Comment: If that's the case then I agree a string is appropriate.