# How do I cast a string in C?

Tags: c, string, casting, integer

I'm making a source file that is supposed to take in 2 directory paths (one in and one out). Then copy the specified file from one directory to the other. I've completed the code, except when I compile it, it prints:

> warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fread’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

This is the part I'm having issues with (I think):

```
if (fp_in != NULL && fp_out != NULL)
{
    char    line[BUFSIZ];

    while (fread(line, sizeof line, fp_in) != NULL)
...
```

Comment: Show more code please: for instance, how did you declare `fp_in`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c ?

Comment: you are missing a parameter, check the docs for [fread](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/)

Comment: First thing to do in a situation like this is, double check the docs. In this case `man fread` (with google, or at shell prompt).

Comment: fread takes 4 [parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/).  You're missing the third parameter, count.  Also the 2nd parameter should be `sizeof(line)`

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Find it strange if it in addition doesn't say something in the direction of `error: too few arguments to function ‘fread’` and `note: expected ‘size_t’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’`

Comment: I used cygwin to compile the code.

Comment: cygwin isn't a compiler. You probably used gcc in cygwin, at which the above messages should be reported. A good compile line would be something like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o outfile source.c`. Optionally add `-std=c89` or `-std=c99`. (I tend to use 89 when ever I do not need 99.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) requires 4 arguments and you just need [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Check both prototypes, if you want to read line by line, You can simply use `fgets()`

```
 while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp_in) != NULL)
         {
         //....
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change usage of `fread` 
from

```
fread(line, sizeof line, fp_in)
```

to

```
num_bytes = fread(line, sizeof(char), sizeof line, fp_in);
```

where `num_bytes` should be defined of type `size_t`. Holds the number of bytes (in this case) read from the file .

---

Read [fread()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fread.html) .

While you refer docs whenever required, make it a mandatory practice that you will read the docs for the library functions you use the very first time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need parentheses in `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: `fread()` does not return  `NULL` . If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero). Make correction in your answer.

Comment: The fgets method seems to be compiling, but I'm yet to test it, since I have to finish off the source file that hands it the correct directory path. Thanks for the answers! I really appreciate it! :D