# How to combined the char value to int?

Tags: c, arrays, int

I have a char array like the following

```
charArray[0] = '1'
charArray[1] = '2'
charArray[2] = '3'
charArray[3] = '4'
charArray[4] = '5'
```

How to combined the char value of above array into a `int` like the following ?
But I don't want to combined all the value in to a `int`

I only want to combined `charArray[0]~charArray[3]` into `int`

```
int number = 1234;
```

How to combined the char value of above array into a string ?

Comment: On what grounds are you disregarding the last digit? No 5's allowed? No more than 4 digits? No result larger than 10,000 allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope, by showing you the following line, this will give you a better idea how to tackle programming problems.

```
int number = (charArray[0] - '0')*1000 + 
             (charArray[1] - '0')*100 + 
             (charArray[2] - '0')*10 + 
             (charArray[3] - '0');
```

Cheers.

Comment: Is the reverse result `4321` intentional? Left to the OP to work out *how* to do it, instead of spoon-feeding an answer?

Comment: @Jongware -- fixed. I think it's helpful to OP to see one pattern for tackling the problem.

Comment: try doing it automatically with an while or for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the atoi function:

```
int atoi (const char * str);
```

recives a string and returns it as a value of type int.

and the function stncpy:

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

Copies the first num characters of source to destination.

Create a new string(with the strncpy function) containing only the 4 first chars of the charArray and then use the function atoi on the result

**This way you could take any size of string you want from the charArray, without manually having to calculate the number**

Example (based on your code, assuming you want to keep the charArray as is without changing it) :

```
int main(void)
{
   char charArray[6]="12345";
   char newcharArray[5];//one char less than charArray
   strncpy(newcharArray,charArray,4);
   printf("%d\n",atoi(newcharArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use alternative methods.

Please check: [Converting string to integer C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c)

You can also use strtoumax() function.

see the example : http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00%2Fstrtoumax.htm