# How to read command-line arguments as integers instead of strings?

Tags: c, argv

Sorry for my question, I know there are a lot similars but I didn't found any that is simple enaugh to help me.

I've started coding in C and try to solve a simple exercise: Read an integers array from command line, sum the elements using the function array_sum and print result. (input example array of 3 elements: 3 0 1 2)

```
int array_sum(int *array,  size_t size);
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int sum=array_sum(argv, argc);
    printf("array_sum: %i\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

my problem is that argv is a char array and the function want an integer array.
Should I convert elements one by one in a new int array? There are better ways?

Comment: `Should I convert elements one by one in a new int array?` Yes.

Comment: @adev   3 0 1 2 is an array of four elements is not it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the first element was intended the lenght of the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv` is an array of pointers to C strings. You **need** to convert the strings into integers first. You can do something like this:

```
int array_sum(int *array,  size_t size);
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int *num_arr = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof *num_arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
      num_arr[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);

    int sum = array_sum(num_arr, argc - 1);
    printf("array_sum: %i\n", sum);

    free(num_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The only way to make the code in `main` shorter is by moving the conversion loop into a separate function that returns the `malloc`ed pointer.

Comment: Thanks, there no need to use malloc because I know the array's lenght

Comment: @adev - If you refer to `argc` then the array length is variable, and you most certainly need `malloc`. Although you can get away with a variable length array if `argc` isn't "too big".

Comment: The call of `array_sum(argv, argc)` would not compile.  Presumably you intended `array_sum(num_arr, (size_t)argc-1)`.

Comment: @Peter - I did, thank you. Got distracted before finishing the example proper.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `char *argv[]` is an array of `char*` pointers supplied from the command line. In order to convert the numbers supplied, you can use the following:

- [`atoi()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm), which converts string arguement to an integer type.
- Or [`strtol()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm), which converts the initial part of a string to a `long int`, given a base.
- Other special functions from C99, alot of which are described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c).

Since `atoi()` has no error checking, it is best to use `strtol()`, which allows extensive error checking.

You should store these converted numbers in a dynamically allocated `int*` pointer, which will need to be allocated on the heap using [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), which was suggested by @StoryTeller in his answer. You could also just declare an array on the stack, such as `int arr[n]`. The problem arises when you want to return this array in a function, which is not possible. Using a pointer in this case would allow more flexibility for abstraction.

> `malloc()`allocates block of memory on the heap, and returns a `void*` pointer to it.

**Note:** `malloc()` should always be checked, as it can return `NULL`. You need to also [`free()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) this pointer at the end.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BASE 10

/* Guessed that your function would look like this */
int array_sum(int *array, size_t size) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *arr = NULL;
    char *endptr = NULL;
    int check, sum;
    size_t ndigits = (size_t)argc-1;

    /* allocate pointer */
    arr = malloc(ndigits * sizeof *arr);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot %zu spaces for integers\n", ndigits);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndigits; i++) {

        /* sufficient checking for strtol(), more can possibly be added here */
        check = strtol(argv[i+1], &endptr, BASE);
        if (endptr != argv[i+1] && *endptr == '\0') {
            arr[i] = check;
        }
    }

    sum = array_sum(arr, ndigits);

    printf("array_sum: %d\n", sum);

    /* pointer is free'd */
    free(arr);
    arr = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Example input:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -o sumcommands sumcommmands.c
$ ./sumcommands 3 2 1
```

Output:

```
array_sum: 6
```

**Note:** You can use more error checking for `strtol()` on the [`Man page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to pass an `int` array as argument to the function ? No need to create an extra `int` array when you can simply do this :

```
int array_sum(char **argv, int argc){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i < argc - 1;i++){
    sum += atoi(argv[i])
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: True, but that's only viable if the requirement of using `array_sum` can be relaxed

Comment: yes @StoryTeller, I must use provided function. The purpose of exercise I think is the interfacing

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi() function to convert **char ** array to **int** . what i see here is each integer you type is converting into **string** rather than **char**.