# Passing integer arguments to the main function in C

Tags: c, multithreading, arguments, program-entry-point

My question is how to pass `int` arguments through `argv[]`.

The form I want to use is the following: while the NTHREADS, and LETTER can be optional, the FILE1 must be provided.

> `./test [-t NTHREADS] [-l LETTER] FILE1`

How can I handle this?

Comment: You can pass to main only variables of char*. You still [can convert to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c).

Comment: Is this a freestanding or hostd environment?

Comment: @Olaf Given the command-line usage and argument style, this is probably the POSIX standard interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. All arguments to `main()` are `char*` by definition. If you want you can convert them, but that's done at your own discretion. There are tools like [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) that make writing interfaces like this a lot easier, and they can be used to do conversion as necessary.

Comment: Not quite right. For a freestanding environment, `main` can have any signature (and name).

Comment: @Olaf: we discuss hosted environments only unless someone specifically points out they're working in a freestanding environment.  There are so many caveats around freestanding environments that it would make everything unanswerable.  Your comment is pointless nitpicking.  Please remove it, and then flag this obsolete.

Comment: i resoved the problem now can i use optional and named parametre  with main ?

Comment: It's worth opening a new question that contains the code you wrote. This is a new problem.

Comment: i cant open a question until 24h new acount , but here is the problem my main fonction need optional and named argument the named one is a file this argument has to be ther in any situation how do i do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the atoi() function, which is available in the stdlib.h standard library, or for a more robust solution you can use strtol(), which is also in stdlib.h

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int numArgs, char **argList )
{
    int num, i;
    for( i = 0; i < numArgs; i++ )
    {
        fprintf( stdout, "\nArgument #%i (\"$s\") is %li as a number.", i, argList[i], strtol(argList[i], NULL, 10) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```