# this c program is not giving correct output.(to convert number string to integer)

Tags: c, string

this is c program to convert number string into integer. I think that the if statement is not getting executed. I want to compare string[a] with the ascii value representented by number in integer i.

```
    //to convert number string to integer
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int a=0, copy[10]={0},len,i;
    char string[10];
    clrscr();
    puts("enter a number string");
    gets(string);
    len=strlen(string);
    while(a<len)
    {
        for(i=48;i<=57;i++)
        {
            if(string[a]==i)
            {
                copy[a]=i-48;
                break;
            }
            a++;
        }

    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    printf("%d",copy[i]);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c

Comment: `a++;` move to after for-loop.

Comment: Hints: 1. don't use TurboC, 2. `gets` has been deprecated more than a decade ago. 3. Don't use "magic numbers" such as `48` but use `'0'` instead.

Comment: Notice the inner loop is comp-letely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is near break statement, Your break statement is being executed without executing `a++;`. Here is the correct code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int a=0, copy[10]={0},len,i;
    char string[10];
    clrscr();
    puts("enter a number string");
    gets(string);
    len=strlen(string);
    while(a<len)
    {
        for(i=48;i<=57;i++)
        {
            if(string[a]==i)
            {
                copy[a]=i-48;
                a++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    printf("%d",copy[i]);
    getch();
}
```