# What is a segmentation fault and why is this program showing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, scanf, strtok

Here I try to get token from a string, separating by space. 
But I'm getting the segmentation fault if I run this program without `while` loop. It is fine, but why?

---

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c[1000];
    int tnum, a, b, d;
    char *n;
    scanf("%d", &tnum);
    while(tnum != 0)
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]s", c);

        n = strtok(c, " ");
        a = atoi(n);

        n = strtok(NULL, " ");
        b = atoi(n);

        n = strtok(NULL, " ");
        d = atoi(n);

        printf("%d\n", a * b * d);
        tnum--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input do you feed the program? And on what line do you get a segfault? (use a debugger to find out)

Comment: Note that a scan set is complete at the `]` of the `%[…]` format specification.  The `s` is a literal character in the format that will not normally match anything, but you won't know that (there's no way for `scanf()` to report that problem).  You're almost certainly getting a segmentation fault because `strtok()` is returning a null pointer when you aren't expecting it to.  You should check that the `scanf()` calls are successful, and you should check that the `strtok()` calls are successful too,

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",c);` --> `scanf(" %[^\n]", c);` should solve your issue. That being said, check the results of `scanf` and `strtok` as [Jonathan Leffler said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605813/what-is-a-segmentation-fault-and-why-is-this-programme-showing-a-segmentation-fa#comment90177205_51605813)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: `%[^\n]s` requires an 's' at the end of the string being inputed? Is that intentional? Know that `%[]` and `%s` are different specifiers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault is usually caused when the program tries to access memory which it is not allowed to use. Read [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/5375464).

In your case it might be caused because of the way you use the character array `c[]` and the `strtok()` function.

[`strtok()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) modifies its first argument based on the delimiters which are in the form of its second argument.

For example, if you do

```
char s[]="hello world how are you?";
strtok(s, " ");
printf("\n%s", s);
```

the output would be just

```
hello
```

and not

```
hello world how are you?
```

because the position with the delimiter is overwritten.This is a reason why `strtok()` can't be used on string literals.

The reason why you don't get error when you try without the `while` loop may be because `c[]` has a few spaces in the part of memory that the program is allowed to access. `strtok()` will go on looking for delimiters till the `\0` denoting end of string is found which may be anywhere since `c[]` has garbage.

---

You haven't initialised `c[]` and it just has some garbage value. And there may or may not be a  (space) which the `strtok()` is to consider as delimiter within the space for 1000 characters that you set aside in `c[]`. And if there is no  within this 1000 bytes, the `strtok()` would look beyond the bounds of the array `c[]` and may modify memory which the program is not allowed to access.

Note that with

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",c);
```

you are asking the program to read everything till a `\n` and then an 's'. The extra s is not necessary. Just '%[^\n]` would've done.

But `scanf()` is not suited for this as it could easily lead to overflow. Read [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2430303/5375464). You could try `fgets()` instead like

```
if( fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin)==NULL )
{
    //something went wrong.
}
```

`fgets()` returns `NULL` upon error.

but keep in mind that `fgets()` would read in the trailing `\n` as well. Read [Removing trailing newline character from `fgets` input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/5375464).

So, as suggested in that post, do something like

```
char *pos;
if( (pos=strchr(c, '\n'))!=NULL )
{
    *pos='\0';
}
```

to replace the `\n` with the nul character denoting the end of string.

Had you done

```
scanf("%[^\n]", c);
```

instead, the `\n` would've remained unconsumed in the input buffer which could cause trouble if not taken care of later.

You may also want to check out [How to convert a string to integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/5375464) as `atoi()` does not allow for proper error checking.

Comment: Thank you. now i understand fully.
Thank you again.