# Is this pointer return safe?

Tags: c, pointers, scope, atoi

A few days ago I wanted to find a safe alternative to `atoi` and found the following code as a response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c) SO question:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    STR2INT_SUCCESS,
    STR2INT_OVERFLOW,
    STR2INT_UNDERFLOW,
    STR2INT_INCONVERTIBLE
} str2int_errno;

str2int_errno str2int(int *out, char *s, int base) {
    char *end;
    if (s[0] == '\0' || isspace(s[0]))
        return STR2INT_INCONVERTIBLE;
    errno = 0;
    long l = strtol(s, &end, base);
    /* Both checks are needed because INT_MAX == LONG_MAX is possible. */
    if (l > INT_MAX || (errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MAX))
        return STR2INT_OVERFLOW;
    if (l < INT_MIN || (errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MIN))
        return STR2INT_UNDERFLOW;
    if (*end != '\0')
        return STR2INT_INCONVERTIBLE;
    *out = l;
    return STR2INT_SUCCESS;
}


int main(void) {
  int i;
    /* Lazy to calculate this size properly. */
    char s[256];

    /* Simple case. */
    assert(str2int(&i, "11", 10) == STR2INT_SUCCESS);
    assert(i == 11);
    printf("%i", i);

    /* Negative number . */
    assert(str2int(&i, "-11", 10) == STR2INT_SUCCESS);
    assert(i == -11);
}
```

[Original code source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923949/11636586)

---

Isn't this unsafe since the *out* pointer is set to a variable that has been defined locally within the function? 
Wouldn't that mean that once the conversion has been done and the local variable goes out of scope it could get overwritten and we couldn't rely on the value anymore?

I might just be missing something, however currently I do not understand how this is a safe way of going about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `out` parameter is a pointer which points to the variable `i` in `main`.  When you later do this:

```
*out = l;
```

This does not change `out` but **dereferences** it and changes the variable it points to, namely `i` in `main`.  So when the function returns `i` is modified.

If `out` pointed to a local variable in `str2int`, then you would have the problem of a pointer pointing to invalid memory.

Answer (score 0):

`*out = l;` doesn't set `out`, it sets `*out`. I.e., whatever it is that `out` is already pointing at, because it *dereferences* the pointer. So long as a valid address is passed in, the function will modify a non-local object.