# Put a number in array, and convert it from char to int

Tags: c, char, type-conversion, int, ascii

Taking in input a number and then put every digit into an array, I have, converted it into a string so that I can put it into an array, but then when I use the cast to remake it a int i get the ascii number..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char num_str[64] = {0};
    int num, cifra;

    printf("Write a number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int len = snprintf(num_str, 64, "%d", num);
    printf("The length is %d\n", len);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cifra = (int)(num_str[i]);
        printf("%d \n", cifra);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `(int)'1'`?

Comment: is 49 the ascii number that represent '1'

Comment: Good, now how does one convert `'1'` into the integer 1? `(int)'1'` doesn't do the trick since it results in 49.

Comment: Yeah that's the question I'm doing :)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c help?

Comment: I need to convert a single char each time to a number not a string

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann maybe by substructing `48`?

Comment: what you mean with substructing 48

Comment: @awwww static int int_result = (int)'1' - (int)'0'

Comment: @awwww `cifra = ((int)(num_str[i])) - 48;` or `cifra = (int)(num_str[i]) - (int)'0';` although i'd rather use a dedicated function like `strtoi` to make it a lot more readable

Comment: also, what happens if someone doesn't write a number? like `A`?

Comment: @JohnSmith could you please show how it would be with strtoi?

Comment: I'd read the number directly into the string. (If you were worried about validation, you'd be checking the return value from `scanf()` — which you should do anyway).  You can then convert the digit characters into the corresponding number by subtracting `'0'` from the (ASCII) digits in the string: `if (scanf("%63s", num_str) == 1) { for (int i = 0; num_str[i] != '\0'; i++) { if (isdigit((unsigned char)num_str[i])) num_str[i] -= '0'; } }`.

Comment: Why not using `strtol`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> convert it from `char` to `int`

Test the character for digit and subtract `'0'`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int cifra = num_str[i];
    if (cifra >= '0' && cifra <= '9') printf("%d\n", cifra - '0');
    else printf("%c\n", cifra);  // such as '-'
}
```