# How do I convert string to integer in this case?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have this problem as a part of my c-programming project. I read users input to char type array (`char*str`) and I need to convert some parts of the string input to integer. The input might be "A smeagol 21 fire 22"

Here is some testing. I try to get x=40. This code's gives x=-4324242. Why this code don't work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *uga[1];
    uga[0] = "10";
    printf("%s\n", uga[0]);
    int x = 50 - (int)uga[0];
    printf("%d",x);     
}
```

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. I suggest you read section 6 of [the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: You have to use `strtol`, `atoi`, or `sscanf` to convert a string that holds a sequence of digit characters representing a decimal number, to an `int` integer.

Comment: Useful links: [1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), [3](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtol`, `sscanf` or  `atoi` to convert a string to int.
For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str[3] = {"10", "20 test of strtol\n", "30"};
    int a = atoi(str[0]);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    char *ptr;
    long int b = strtol(str[1], &ptr, 10); // you can alse use strtoll for long long int
    printf("b = %ld, string: %s", b, ptr);
    int c;
    sscanf(str[2], "%d", &c);
    printf("c = %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 10
b = 20, string:  test of strtol
c = 30
```

In your code, `uga[0]` is a pointer that points to a character. So `(int) uga[0]` just cast the address of the `char` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting a `char` pointer or array to `int` or another numeric type will not give you the numeric value of the text in the string.

You should use the functions `strtol` (signed), `strtoul` (unsigned) to accomplish this:

```
char *str = "123ABC";
char *pStop;     

// (Arguments: string to parse, pointer to character that stops the parse, base/radix)
int value = strtol(str, &pStop, 10);
```

After this, `value` will be `123`, and `pStop` will point to the 'A' in `str`. The second argument can be `NULL` if you don't care about it, but it's useful for processing a string with lots of numbers in it between non-numeric text.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems in your code.

1. uga isn't a string as you think, but an array of strings containing only one string that has no memory allocated. To fix that, you should declare uga as it follows `char uga[max_size_of_your_string] = "Initialization if you want to";`
2. Thus `(int)uga[0];` won't work as you expect, because you're trying to convert an address to an integer.

I advise you to declare properly your string `uga`, and to take a look at the different ways of converting a numerical string to integer here : [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf` also like this for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "A smeagol 21 fire 22";
    int a, b;

    if (2 != sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9] %d %*[^0-9] %d", &a, &b))
      return printf("Error\n"), 1;

    printf("%d %d",a, b);     
}
```

Output

```
21 22
```

`%*[^0-9]` will match any non digit character and it will be discarded (because of the `*`). `sscanf` return the number of variables which it was able to fill. Which should be 2 here, otherwise something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `atoi()` under `stdlib.h`. 
For instance,

```
    int val; 
    char strn1[] = "12546"; 
  
    val = atoi(strn1); 
    printf("String value = %s\n", strn1); 
    printf("Integer value = %d\n", val); 
  
    char strn2[] = "12Ge 1 89"; 
    val = atoi(strn2); 
    printf("String value = %s\n", strn2); 
    printf("Integer value = %d\n", val);
```

## Output:

String value = 12546 
Integer value = 12546 
String value = 12Ge 1 89 
Integer value = 12

Hope it helps!
gives the