# char** argv passed as array of string

Tags: c

What I know about this code is that in the **void cylinder function** char** argv is a array of string and numbers are stored in this. I dont know how to convert this array into the int values and then use it.

```
    void cylinder(int argv_size, char** argv){
    //comlete this code
    }

    int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    char* *a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        a[i] = (char *)malloc(1020 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",a[i]);
        }
    cylinder(n,a);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be asking for people to write a complete implementation for you. Please see [ask].

Comment: use `atoi` to convert strings to ints.

Comment: that's not true what I want to know is how do I convert them because into their int values.

Comment: It seems unclear what the input format looks like. Maybe clarify that?

Comment: Input is just an integer value.

Comment: @DrkEthics: No, they are character strings containing a (presumably decimal) representation of integers. You need to keep very clear the difference between value and representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check if some arguments/ no arguements have been passed:

```
if(argc==1) 
        printf("\nNo Command Line Argument Passed Other Than Program Name"); 
    if(argc>=2) 
    { 
        printf("\nNumber Of Arguments Passed: %d",argc); 

        for(int counter=0 ; counter<argc ; counter++) 
            printf("\nargv[%d]: %s",counter,argv[counter]); 
    }
```

Then, to convert the passed integer(passed as a string) value use `atoi`, like: `atoi(argv[1])` if only one integer value has been passed.

Note: use `#include<stdlib.h>` for `atoi()`

Answer (score 0):

I see some disadvantage in your code:

```
scanf("%s",a[i]);
```

Should change to (see [disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf) ):

```
scanf("%1019s",a[i]);
//OR
fgets(a[i], 1020, stdin);
```

You should check the result of `malloc` function, and do not cast `malloc` as i see you allocated for `a[i]`:

```
char* *a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
if(!a) {
//handle the error
return -1; // for example
}
```

and

```
a[i] = malloc(1020 * sizeof(char));
if(!a[i]) {
//handle the error
}
```

You have to free the memory of each `a[i]` and `a` after `cylinder` function to avoid memory-leaks.

For `cylinder` function:

```
void cylinder(int argv_size, char** argv){
    for(int i = 0; i < argv_size; i++) {
        // convert argv[i] to int by using sscanf, atoi, strol, etc.
        // for example i use atoi function:
        printf("value of (int)argv[i] = %d", atoi(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

You can also find other function for converting `string` to `int` in this link [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c)