# Best way to convert a regex match into an integer in C?

Tags: c, regex, string

I am using the standard `<regex.h>` library to match a complex string. Some matches are integers and my current solution is to use `to_integer`:

```
int to_integer(regmatch_t match, const char* str) {
    char buffer[16];
    int end = match.rm_eo - match.rm_so;
    memcpy(buffer, &str[match.rm_so], end);
    buffer[end] = '\0';
    return atoi(buffer);
}

struct data {
    int foo, bar, baz;
};

struct data fetch(char *string) {
   int groups = 4;
   regmatch_t matches[groups];
   if (regexec(&regex, string, groups, matches, 0)) abort();

   return (struct data){
       to_integer(matches[1], string),
       to_integer(matches[2], string),
       to_integer(matches[3], string)
   };
}
```

Is there a more elegant way that does not involve an intermediate buffer?

Without an intermediate buffer, the following would eventually fail: `([0-9]{3})[0-9]{2}`. I also cannot modify `str` in place because it is constant.

**EDIT**

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c) I wrote the following:

```
int to_integer(regmatch_t match, const char* str) {
    const char *end = &str[match.rm_eo];
    return strtol(&str[match.rm_so], (char**)&end , 10);
}
```

Unfortunately, the explicit cast `(char*)` is quite ugly. My previous solution involving a copy of the string looks a bit safer IMHO.

Comment: @bruno it does not work if the current match is directly followed by a number

Comment: Your current approach seems fine. Maybe some logic to make sure you're not going  to write past the end of `buffer`.

Comment: Please check the [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c) thread.

Comment: In the EDIT section, the `end` argument to `strtol()` is a pure output argument, but the code seems to treat it as an input argument, or as an in/out argument.  You may as well pass a NULL pointer since you don't look at `end` after calling `strtol()`.  If you decide to keep it, it may as well be uninitialized and of the correct type (`char *`).  If the regex doesn't necessarily consume all the digits in a digit sequence, using `strtol()` is not correct.  It will read past the end of the matched digits.