# Getting string between two given characters

Tags: c

> quote
> I have input something like `!Hello world! - 123 123 -` and I need to get it into `struct { char *string; int a; int b;}`  Can you help me?

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char *string;
} Smth;
//-----------(size=(already known size of input))
Smth *smth = (*Smth)malloc(sizeof(smth));
smth.string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
sscanf(input, "!%[^!]! - %d %d - ", smth.string, &smth.a, &smth.b); // doesn't work for me
```

Comment: Perhaps look at the rexex library like this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64412234/1216776

Comment: You could use multiple `scanf` or just one `fgets`

Comment: you just did a small error, see my answer

Comment: It would help if you show us how `smth` is declared and "allocated"?

Answer (score 2):

**before you edit your question**

the call

> ```
> sscanf("!%[^!]! - %d %d - ",string,&a,&b);
> ```

is not the one you want, you missed to give the string to parse as the first argument, so the string to parse is the format you wanted to use and the used format is the perhaps not initialized value of *string*

You wanted :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char string[32];
  int a,b;
  const char * i = "!Hello world! - 123 123 -";
  
  if (sscanf(i, "!%31[^!]! - %d %d - ", string,&a,&b) == 3)
    printf("'%s' %d %d\n", string, a, b);
  else
    put("error");
  
  return 0;
}
```

does the work :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'Hello world' 123 123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Notice I added in your original format a max length for the read string to not take the risk to write out of *string* and then to have an undefined behavior. If you do not want to manage yourself the array for *string* you can use the option `%m` but is not always available.

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking the input string for `sscanf`. See example below.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   char *string;
} Smth;


int main(void)
{
   Smth smth;
   sscanf(
      "!Hello world! - 123 123 -",
      "!%m[^!]! - %i %i -",
      &smth.string,
      &smth.a,
      &smth.b);
   printf("Str: `%s' a:%d b:%d\n", smth.string, smth.a, smth.b);
   free(smth.string);
   return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Given your change in question

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
   char* string;
} Smth;


int main(void)
{
   size_t size  = 30u;
   char input[] = "!Hello world! - 123 123 -";

   Smth* smth   = (Smth*) malloc(sizeof(Smth));
   smth->string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
   sscanf(input, "!%29[^!]! - %d %d - ", smth->string, &smth->a, &smth->b);

   printf("Str: %s a:%d b:%d\n", smth->string, smth->a, smth->b);

   free(smth->string);
   free(smth);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DanielBlažek I see a `char * string` in your struct. Did you allocate memory for that string? You need memory to contain the string and `sscanf()` won't do that for you.

Comment: @Blastfurnace the format uses the option *m*, I also speak about that way in my answer

Comment: @bruno Oh, it's the first time I've seen that GNU lib C extension.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, this is practical but not standard

Comment: @bruno It's also in POSIX. Hmm, I learn something new every day.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, even 'only' answering we learn ;-)