# reading and printing unsigned int from file

Tags: c, file, unsigned-integer

I am trying to print and read unsigned ints from a .txt file. I am using fprintf to print the unsigend int, (menualy checking the file presents the wanted values), but when reading it, I get a weird offset to all the values I read (same offset beween all reads, but not every run of the program), here is the reading code I am using:

```
unsigned int tempDuration = (unsigned int)fileFgets(file);
```

and this is fileFgets:

```
char tempStr[MAX_STR_SIZE] = { 0 };
char* str = 0;
fgets(tempStr, MAX_STR_SIZE, file);
tempStr[strcspn(tempStr, "\n")] = 0;
str = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempStr) * sizeof(str));
strcpy(str, tempStr);
return str;
```

I am using this function becuse it is ment to read both strings and unsinged ints, seperated by '\n', but am open for using diffrent solutions for both or either. **(reading the strings works as intended)**

Comment: You can't use a cast to convert a string to an integer. Use `strtoul()` or `sscanf()`.

Comment: @Yoav Raman As you wrote the function should read unsigned integers from the file instead of strings.

Comment: Other issues: `strlen(tempStr)` needs to be `strlen(tempStr)+1` to account for the string NUL terminator. `sizeof(str)` should be `sizeof(*str)` or `sizeof(char)`

Comment: Beware of memory leaks when allocating memory for the string like that. Also, if you need to allocate and copy a string, use `strdup` to avoid the very common issue that @kaylum already highlighted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c)

Comment: @kaylum fully, no. As I am using an unsinged int and not a normal one, but in my use case it is good enogh.

Answer (score 0):

Casting from an array of characters to an unsigned integer will actually cast the pointer and not the string itself. You need to convert it using [strtoul()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Replacing the `'\n'` character isn't required because strtoul stopps at the first character which is not a valid digit.

I modified your function :

```c
unsigned int fileFgets(file)
{
    char tempStr[MAX_STR_SIZE] = { 0 };
    fgets(tempStr, MAX_STR_SIZE, file);
    return strtoul(tempStr, NULL, 0);
}
```