# reading a number from the command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

Please forgive me for asking this simple question, but I only started C recently with the original C book by Kernigham and Ritchie, using Notepad++ (as VSCode just throws errors when I try to compile anything and I don't know yet how to overcome that), and using gcc from the command line.

Anyway, the question I have is, how do I read a number from a command line argument?

For example, `myProgram 2`

I know that the `main()` definition is as shown below, and that `argc` is a counter, and `argv` is a pointer to a character array (I think this is right) containing the command lines.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

The question I have is, how do I convert the character `2` (which is my command line argument, it could be any number) to an `int`?

I've googled and a few things come across casting, which I believe is changing one data type to another, and I have tried:

```
int a = (int)(argv[1]);
```

which compiles, but with a warning saying "cast from pointer to integer of different size". It compiles, but then won't run.

I suspect the answer I need is simple, it's just beyond my knowledge at the moment.

Comment: The easiest way to convert a string to an int is to use [`atoi()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: The warning is because argv is an array of strings--a `char[][]`. C doesn't contain implicit string to int conversion as a language feature, so it tries to interpret the `char*` as an int, giving you the address of the first character.

Comment: Do not forget to first check that there IS something there. `if( argc > 1) ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c)

Comment: @JakobLovern -- note that `atoi` and friends are problematic conversion functions: they have undefined behavior when their input can't be represented as a value in the target type, and they don't report errors during conversion. `strtol` and friends are better choices.

Comment: BrianDawe, if the command line had `abc` instead of `2`, what result would you like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having issues as "argv[1]" really is a pointer to a character array.  What you probably would want to do is use the "atoi" conversion function which will convert a string to an integer.  Following is a proof-of-principle code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        i = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    printf("i: %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Following is some sample terminal output.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Args/bin/Release$ ./Args 144
i: 144
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Note that `i` will be uninitialized if no command-line parameter is given. Accessing the value of an uninitialized variable, such as in a `printf()` call, is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `printf( "i: %d\n", atoi( argv[ 1 ] ) );` INSIDE the `if( )` block, perhaps? `:-)`

Comment: Yup.  Good catch.

Comment: In principle, it's also a good idea to print a usage message to guide the user if the number of arguments is wrong.  Similarly, it's not a good idea to ignore arguments, so the code should either complain when `argc != 2` or should iterate over all the arguments (only complaining when no arguments are supplied).  Using `atoi()` means that `./Args 12dozen` or `./Args 1gross` will work (producing 12 and 1).  Using `strtol()` or a similar function gives better control.   Error messages should be printed on `stderr`.  And, as it is just a learning exercise, I suspect my comments are OTT.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions. NoDakker that worked a treat thank you. Pointers are "fun" :D I'm sure ill get  my head around it. And @JakobLovern I have made a note of your suggestion also and will look into it

Comment: Fe2O3 Thanks and also Thanks Jonathan I have screen capped you're reply so that I can try and do just that better to learn the right way from the start :D