# why ERANGE won't triggered when using strtol

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static bool
ReadDimensionInt(char **srcptr, int *result, const char *origStr)
{
    char       *p = *srcptr;
    // printf("p=%s\n", p);
    /* don't accept leading whitespace */
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) && *p != '-' && *p != '+')
    {
        *result = 0;
        return true;            /* leave 'src' unmodified */
    }

    errno = 0;
    *result = strtol(p, srcptr, 10);

    if (errno == ERANGE)
    {
        printf("array bound is out of range\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int 
main(void)
{

    char    *s = "2147483648111";
    char    *result;
    int testresult;
    bool    readok;

    readok = ReadDimensionInt(&s, &testresult, s);
    
    if (readok)
        printf("test_result=%d\n", testresult);
    else
        printf("read dimension failed");

    return 0;
}
```

expect invoke
`printf("array bound is out of range\n");`
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html

printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long)); return 8.

Comment: Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long));`. What does that print?

Comment: You are doing `*result = strtol(p, srcptr, 10);` when `result` is `int *`. That can easily be invalid if `LONG_MAX != INT_MAX` on your system. Also, if you have 64-bit `long` on your system, `2147483648111` is well within range.

Comment: @user3386109 return 8.

Comment: Well there you have it. Your `long` is 64-bit. The max supported value should be `9223372036854775807` (a bit higher than `2147483648111` :P). Additionally, your `int` is going to be 32-bit, so your assignment `*result = strtol(p, srcptr, 10)` is invalid. Your `result` should be `long *` not `int *`. Either change it or use a temporary `long` variable and check its bounds before assigning it to an `int`.

Comment: As any other integer type, the size (and range) of `long` depends on the compiler and the target platform. Windows and MSVC have 32-bit `long` even on 64-bit systems. GCC typically uses 64-bit `long` on all 64-bit systems, and 32-bit `long` on 32-bit systems.

Comment: seems this is very bullet-proof. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923949/15603477 will try this one. @MarcoBonelli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtol` converts to a `long` and only gives `ERANGE` if the result is out of range for `long`.  You appear to be converting to `int` so you actually want something more like:

```
errno = 0;
long val = strtol(p, srcptr, 10);
if (errno == ERANGE || val > INT_MAX || val < INT_MIN) {
    printf("array bound is out of range\n");
    return false;
} else {
    *result = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please note that return value `strtol` save to `long` type or `long long` type.

The depend on how many size of `sizeof(long) or sizeof(long long)`, if `sizeof(long)` is 4 in 32-bit computer, then output `array bound is out of range`, if `sizeof(long)` is 8 in 64-bit computer, then output `test_result=2147483648111` when you save return of `strtol` function as `long` at `sizeof(long)` is 8 status.

And in your code `if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) && *p != '-' && *p != '+')`, if check it should `return false` rather then `return true`. (Note that you set value of `*result` to 0).

And `if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) && *p != '-' && *p != '+')` should be `if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) || *p == '-' || *p == '+')`, because of when `*p` is not digit or `*p` is '-' or `*p` is '+', then should return false. `*p` is either not a number or `-` or `+`, there is only one status, so this mean `if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) && *p != '-' && *p != '+')` is alway check failed, code in `if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) && *p != '-' && *p != '+')` will never run.

see below code that I change type of result `int` to `long` when declare, so parameter is `long* result`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

static bool
ReadDimensionInt(char **srcptr, long *result, const char *origStr)
{
    char       *p = *srcptr;
    // printf("p=%s\n", p);
    /* don't accept leading whitespace */
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char) *p) || *p == '-' || *p == '+')
    {
        *result = 0;
        printf("******conversion could not be performed\n");
        return false;            /* leave 'src' unmodified */
    }

    errno = 0;
    *result = strtol(p, srcptr, 10);

    if (errno == ERANGE)
    {
        printf("array bound is out of range\n");
        return false;
    }else if (errno == EINVAL){
        printf("conversion could not be performed\n");
        *result = 0;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int 
main(void)
{

    char    *s = "2147483648111";
    char    *result;
    long testresult = 1;
    bool    readok;
    
    printf("sizeof long is %zu, signed long max is %ld\n", sizeof(long), LONG_MAX);

    readok = ReadDimensionInt(&s, &testresult, s);
    
    if (readok)
        printf("test_result=%ld\n", testresult);
    else
        printf("read dimension failed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
sizeof long is 8, signed long max is 9223372036854775807
test_result=2147483648111
```