# (Macro error) error: ‘argv’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, pointers, command-line, macros, command-line-arguments

I have been trying to write this program that simulates a pop machine, and Im not supposed to use any hard coded variables or global variables.
This only leaves me with Macros, but the macro wont accept my command line arguments for some reason.

It should accept one command line argument of type int, and then define a macro for use later as that value.
Ive tried casting the argument as int as well, and using *argv[1] since its a pointer, no luck.

My code is as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
#define PRICE *argv[1]
if (argc == 1){
        printf("Please specify the selling price as a command line argument.\n">
        printf("Usage: ./pop [price]");
        exit(1);
}
//#define PRICE (int)argv[1] //Was 40 previously.
if (*argv[1] % MULTIPLE != 0){//Protective if-else case
        printf("Price must be a multiple of %d.\n",MULTIPLE);
        exit(1);//Use exit to terminate since input is invalid.
}
printf("Welcome to my C pop Machine!\n");
```

Tried casting, tried dereferencing the pointer, and using it directly.

Comment: There are no other type command line arguments than `char*` so you need to convert it to int first. Using `*argv[1]` won’t do that and isn’t a sensible thing to do. Look up converting strings to ints in C and use that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `#define PRICE *argv[1]` syntactically, except it may confuse in some expressions, e.g. `PRICE++`. Use parentheses to avoid ambiguity: `#define PRICE (*argv[1])`. What is exact error message? Note `*argv[1]` is first character of argument, i.e. when you run `./pop 10` PRICE will be 49. Probably not what you want.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *'hardcoded variables'* actually? Constants?

Answer (score 2):

> It should accept one command line argument of type int.

The command line arguments are of type `char *`. To convert one to an `int`, use `atoi()`/`strtol()` et cetera.

If you wish to use the converted value in another function, pass it as an argument. `argv` would not be visible outside of `main()`, nor would casting it to an `int` do anything meaningful.

See: [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/20017547)

Answer (score 0):

As you are a beginner in C, I strongly suggest these recommendations:

- learn to indent the code correctly
- do not use macros.
- read tutorials and books to learn the basics.

Command line arguments are passed as C strings to the program.  To convert a C string representing a number to the corresponding `int` value, you can use the library functions `atoi()` or `strtol()` declared in `<stdlib.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int MULTIPLE = 10;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Please specify the selling price as a command line argument.\n");
        printf("Usage: ./pop price\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int price = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (price % MULTIPLE != 0) {
        printf("Price must be a multiple of %d.\n", MULTIPLE);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Welcome to my C pop Machine!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, I greatly appreciate it, I hope you all enjoy your day.

Comment: @natemichael: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.