# How can I determine if scanf read what was specified in format?

Tags: c, integer, scanf

I have a program that defines a variable `int data`

The program uses  `scanf("%d",&data)` to read data from stdin.
If the data from stdin is not an integer, I have to print error message.

I tried `if(scanf("%d",&data) ==EOF){ printf("error");return 1;}`

It didn`t works for me. So, how can I determine if scanf failed or succeeded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`scanf`'s return value is an integer, telling you how many items were succesfully read. If your single integer was read successfully, `scanf` will return 1.

e.g.

```
int items_read = scanf("%d", &data);

if (items_read != 1) {
    //It was not a proper integer
}
```

There is a great discussion on reading integers [here, on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420629/convert-string-to-integer-sscanf-or-atoi/3421555#3421555).

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` returns the number of items successfully read. You can check if it failed by checking against 1, because you're reading one item:

```
if (scanf("%d", &data) != 1)
    // error
```