# Explicit conversion C

Tags: c, type-conversion

If i have the following :

```
char id[5]="1";
```

and I want to use the id as a integer,i have to convert it first or is enough  `(int)id` to use the value from that string ?

Comment: This question should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420629/convert-string-to-integer-sscanf-or-atoi

Comment: Especially note that `(int)id` will compile and is valid C, but does not do what you think it would. It will return the (first) memory address of the string, i.e. the value of the pointer itself.

Answer (score 4):

No... you would need to convert it using a function call such as `int n = atoi( id )`

A char array is just that... an array of char... it is not a number in the sense that you're thinking. You need to use a function call to convert it from the string representation of a value to the actual numerical integer value you're looking for.

Comment: well, technically it is a number, an ASCII character code, but it doesn't map to the numeral.

Comment: Fair enough -- edited to clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can use [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) to convert the string to an integer:

```
char id[5] = "1";
int n = atoi(id); // n = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not provide type conversions between strings and numerical data.

To convert from a string to an int, you need to use `atoi` or (better) `strtol`.
`strtol` is better, because it does not result in undefined behaviour if the input string is not convertable to a number, and it allows you to detect cases like `"42xyz"` and react correctly.