# Converting string value to int equivalent in C

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this:

```
int main()
{
char a[100];
int i = 0;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%c", &a[i]);

printf("The number you've entered is: %d", a[i] - '0');
}
```

Brief summary: I am trying to convert a number stored in a `char` array to its `int` equivalent. I know in C#, you use the `intparse` command, but because there isn't such one in C, I do not know what to do. When I input a two digit number, it is only outputting the first digit, of the input `char`.

Comment: use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) of <stdlib.h>.

Comment: For one, the return value of `main` should be int. By the way, I ran your program, and there seems to be nothing wrong with it.

Comment: i tried int too.. but wasn't working.. lemme check again

Comment: same thing.. gives me a totally different output.. not garbage i guess

Comment: Your code is just confusing ! reading a single character and asking for  conversion of two characters into its int equivalent !

Comment: i wonder you got a vote up for this question !

Comment: Ok.. @kaustav.. please tell me then, how will to accept a number, and store it in a char variable, and the print out the int equivalent?

Comment: and i am not reading a single char.. it is an array bound to accept 101 characters

Comment: It can not be stored in an int 100 digits.

Answer (score 3):

strtol sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char str[16], *endp;
    int value;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    value = strtol(str, &endp, 0);
    if(*endp == '\n' || *endp == '\0'){
        printf("The number you've entered is: %d\n", value);
    } else {
        printf("invalid number format!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to print ASCII value of char the no need to do `a[i] - '0'`.
Try this

```
 printf("The number you've entered is: %d", a[i]);
```

If you are talking about string then first change your `scanf` statement to

```
scanf("%s", a);
```

or better to use `fgets` library function instead of `scanf`;

```
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
```

and then use  `strtol` function.

Comment: a multiple of 10 gives me 49, basically. this includes 1.. not sure whats going on

Comment: Lol (to downvoter)..... `%c` reads only a single character at a time not two (`10`)

Comment: %3d isn't of much help either

Comment: No. Its is out of context here.

Comment: scanf("%c", a): gives a garbage value

Comment: @AnonymousPerson; Oops! That was Typo. Its `scanf("%s", a); `. See the edit.

Comment: scanf("%c",a);  Here u r trying to print the character format of address of array a, and hence address is generally a large value so for this big value no corresponding character and hence some unpredictable pattern will display on your screen.

Comment: Let c is a character then to print its value in integer format then just use ("%d",c); No need of doing any thing.

Comment: @asifaftab87: didn't work.. can you check if there is any other modification that needs to be done with the coding

Comment: I already said that that which character value you want to print in its int format then store it in a character variable then print it just by using %d format. Second thing that I think so that you want to print int format of '10' then it is wrong because '10' is not a character it will take may be first as char and left the remaining portion. So even if you want to print '10' int ascii then you to write some codes means you to write your own code to implement this and it is possible

Comment: ITT: Code posted in OP has nothing to do with question OP asks.

Answer (score 0):

OP method of `scanf("%c", &a[i]);` only handles a 1 character input.

To read the entire line, suggest using `fgets()` to read.
The convert to a `long` using `strtol()`.
Watch for potential errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  // use long to match strtol()
  long i;
  // size buffer to handle any legitimate input 
  char a[sizeof i * 3 + 3];
  char *endptr;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin) == NULL) {
    // If you would like to handle uncommon events ...
    puts("EOForIOError");
    return 1;
  }
  errno = 0;
  i = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
  if(*endptr != '\n' /* text after number */ || 
      endp == a      /* no text */           || 
      errno          /* overflow */) {
    printf("Invalid number %s", a);
  }
  else {
    printf("The number you've entered is: %ld\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
char myarray[5] = {'-', '4', '9', '3', '\0'};
int i;
sscanf(myarray, "%d", &i); // i will be -493
```

---

**Edit** (borrowed from [1]):

There is a wonderful question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420629/convert-string-to-integer-sscanf-or-atoi) on the site that explains and compares 3 different ways to do it - `atoi`, `sscanf` and `strtol`. Also, there is a nice more-detailed insight into `sscanf` (actually, the whole family of `*scanf` functions).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

char a[100];

int final=0,integer;

int i;

printf("Enter a number: ");

gets(a);

for(i=0;a[i]>='0'&&a[i]<='9';++i)

{

integer=a[i] - '0';

final=final*10+integer;

} 

    enter code here

printf("The integer is %d ", final);

}
```

Comment: It's best if you also explain your code, it makes it a lot easier to understand an answer rather than blindly copying it.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.